# Get nodes BETWEEN two nodes

Tags: neo4j

How can I get the nodes on a path of variable length between two nodes, exclusive, in Neo4j?

Example

N1 -RELATIONSHIP-> N2 -RELATIONSHIP-> N3 -RELATIONSHIP-> N4

I'd like to get N2 and N3

I do not know the length of the path beforehand, I only know the starting node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Match p= (n1)-[r:RELATIONSHIP*]->(n4) return filter(x IN nodes(p) 
              WHERE x<>n1 AND x<>n4) AS pathNodes
```

try this

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that the amount of nodes between the first and last node can be variable

Comment: @Lamoni you should update your question with that information (and don't put in in **Edit**, or **Update** when you do so, we have edit history for that).

Comment: The above will work for any number of nodes between n1 and n4 provided you know what n1 and n4

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the nodes with in the path like this

```
MATCH p=(n1)-->(b)-->(n4)
RETURN filter(x IN nodes(p) 
          WHERE id(x) <> id(n1) AND id(x) <>id(n4)) AS allNodes
```

Here is the reference doc http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html

Comment: How can I use this to not get n1 and n4 in that list? Thanks. also, there could be a variable amount of N in the path

Comment: What is ( b) in your query